# classic ASP error when sending an email through script

Tags: asp-classic, smtp

A website within our management has a problem. This is an classic asp site that needs to mail for certain actions. But with sending an email we get the following error:

```
CDO.Message.1 error '80040213'
The transport failed to connect to the server
```

The used code:

```
Set objCDOSYSMail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set objCDOSYSCon = Server.CreateObject ("CDO.Configuration")
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "x.y.z"
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "mail@example.com"
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = ""
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = 1
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
objCDOSYSCon.Fields.Update
Set objCDOSYSMail.Configuration = objCDOSYSCon
objCDOSYSMail.From = "mail@example.com"
objCDOSYSMail.To = ""
objCDOSYSMail.Subject = ""
objCDOSYSMail.HTMLBody = ""
objCDOSYSMail.Send
```

**What we already tried:**

1# Changing the following option:

```
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = 1
```

to

```
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = 0
```

But when we tested the change we received the following error:

```
CDO.Message.1 error '80040211'
SMTP service is returning not successful
```

2# Changing the option:

```
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
```

to:

```
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 1
```

The following error showed when we tested the change:

```
CDO.Message.1 error '80040222'
The pickup directory path is required and was not specified.
```

SOLVED:

We changed the code back to were we started with the following changes:

```
Set objCDOSYSMail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set objCDOSYSCon = Server.CreateObject ("CDO.Configuration")
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "server.serverdomain.com"
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "mail@example.com"
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = ""
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = 1
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
objCDOSYSCon.Fields.Update
Set objCDOSYSMail.Configuration = objCDOSYSCon
objCDOSYSMail.From = "mail@example.com"
objCDOSYSMail.To = ""
objCDOSYSMail.Subject = ""
objCDOSYSMail.HTMLBody = ""
objCDOSYSMail.Send
```

Comment: Seems like your not familiar with your SMTP configuration, if you were using SSL to connect I doubt that the SMTP port would be 25. Also changing the `sendusing` setting will affect how CDO is going to send the message. If you change to use a pickup directory locally it will require a location to save the files to for processing, hence the error.